# How can grep return a different number of matches?

Tags: grep, pattern-matching

I need to grep a file (24 lines) into two files (which are kind of big).

The original files contains 24 lines that resemble this string:

```
AATGGACGCTTAAC[A|C|T][A|C|G]CGGC[A|T]TCGGAT
```

I do the following:

```
grep -f aList hugeFile_N*.csv | wc -l
4396868
```

Then, to double check that everything went fine, I split the file in two files and I use both of them through another grep:

```
cat aList | head -n 12 > firstHalf
cat aList | tail -n +13 > secondHalf
grep -f firstHalf hugeFile_N*.csv | wc -l
2169008
grep -f secondHalf hugeFile_N*.csv | wc -l
2228046
```

Now, I was expecting that the total number of matches from the two separately grepped files would be equal to the number of matches I found for the original file. But, as you can see:

```
2169008 + 2228046 = 4397054
4397054 != 4396868
```

This is not the case. We have 186 matches that are missing. What is going on here?

I also did some investigations into the (actually very simple) files. Here I grep the results from the two separate halves:

```
grep -f <(cat firstHalf secondHalf) hugeFile_N*.csv > together
```

Then I grep the two halves separately:

```
grep -f firstHalf hugeFile_N*.csv > separately
grep -f secondHalf hugeFile_N*.csv >> separately
```

And, as already shown, the number of matches is different:

```
wc -l together
4396868 together
wc -l separately
4397054 separately
```

However, the number of unique matches is the same:

```
sort -u together | wc -l
3735836
sort -u separately | wc -l
3735836
```

Interestingly, if I grep the two halves in the original file, I have no matches at all. I wonder why this is happening:

```
grep -f ../code/firstHalf ../code/aList | wc -l
0
grep -f ../code/secondHalf ../code/aList | wc -l
0
```

I am 100% sure that both halves are present in `aList` since I can see it with my editor (they are 12 lines each, so it's not even that difficult to see by naked eyes).

I feel I am doing something wrong with the `grep` but...what?

All the lines in `aList` are unique.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`grep` only looks for lines that match *at least one* of the patterns given. With 24 patterns in `aList`, it's possible that one from the first half and one from the second half match. That would mean you'd get matches on the same line for both `grep -f firstHalf` and `grep -f secondHalf`. Running the two halves of the pattern list separately would double count those lines.

E.g.

```
$ cat test.txt 
abc 
foo
bar
foobar
$ cat patterns 
foo
bar
$ grep -c -f patterns  test.txt 
3
```

but of course also:

```
$ grep -c -e foo test.txt
2
$ grep -c -e bar test.txt
2
```

And 2+2 > 3.

If all the lines are distinct, counting unique matching lines would of course be a way to remove that effect. You could use `grep -n` to add line numbers to the output, making each output line unique. Of course remember that by default `grep` looks for matches anywhere on the line, and if that's not what you want, you need to use `grep -x`.

Note also that `[A|C|T]` means to match any of the characters `A`, `C`, `T` or `|`. If you don't want or need to match the pipe character, use just `[ACT]`. Or, if you need alternation, you have to use extended regexes (`grep -E`), and then `(this|that)` (with parenthesis, not brackets). But that's not necessary as long as all the alternatives are single characters.

Comment: sorry, I didn't say that all the lines in `aList` are unique! I am editing the question accordingly. Also, I don't understand what do you mean when you mention using `grep -n`.

Comment: @gabt, all patterns in the file might be unique, but they might still match the same lines in data. Like in my example, `foo` and `bar` are distinct, but both still match the line `foobar`.

Comment: ok, I need to do some experiments in order to properly understand what is going on here. baseline is that I will not be able to compare the results from grepping the whole list with grepping the two halves. I have to consider them as two separate, different things and I have to expect different outcomes. Is this correct?

Comment: @gabt, well, in a way, yes. The lines in the file given by `-f` are _patterns_, not fixed strings. The patterns could match multiple lines, and multiple patterns could match the same line. So there's no 1:1 relationship. As for splitting the list, it's the same as asking a bunch of students how many have taken course A and how many have taken course B. The total of those numbers could be different from the number of students who have taken _either_ A or B (i.e. have taken at least one of A and B). Indeed the total could be higher than the total number of students.

Comment: ok, great! thank you.

Comment: E.g. the pattern `GGC[A|T]` (to take a short example) would match both `GGCA` and `GGCT`, but also `ABCGGCAXYZ` (since it's not locked to start/end of the line). And that could also be matched by `AB[DEF]GG`.